# Finding Roots of 7th Deg Polynomial Using Calculus

Tags: calculus

I had a test question that asked for the roots of a 7th degree polynomial, is there a way to do this involving calculus? I can just do some brutal algebraic manipulations to get the roots, but I figure there must be a calculus way. This test was also focused on Mean Value Theorem, Int. Value Theorem, etc... I'm not sure if those play into it? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Sorry I forgot to include the polynomial :/

$f(x) = x^7- x^4 -12x$

Yes the question was asking to find all the roots

Comment: This is well-known (among mathematicians) to be impossible in general, so I'm 99\% sure there was a particular trick involved. Without more information, I can't say any more other than that there must be at least one real root since $7$ is odd.

Comment: Please post that seven degree polynomial.

Comment: Usual first step is to test for rational roots, that shouldn't be difficult.

Comment: If you don't post the polynomial in question, there's really nothing anyone can do to help.

Comment: Was the question asking you to find the roots or about something else with roots.

Comment: Is there something which still needs clarification to answer your question? If not it would be appropriate to accept one of the two answers.

Comment: yes sorry I always forget about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to solve the equation,

$$x^7-x^4-12x = 0,$$

first we note that there is an overall factor of $x$. This can be factored out and we see that one of our roots is $x=0$. What remains after factoring is,

$$x^6-x^3-12 = 0.$$

Now we notice that this is really a quadratic in terms of the variable $x^3$/ This is because the only powers of $x$ are $x^3$ and $x^6= (x^3)^2$. Let $u=x^3$ and note,

$$x^6-x^3-12 = 0$$
 $$(x^3)^2-(x^3)-12 = 0$$
 $$u^2-u-12 = 0$$

This is a quadratic equation in $u$ which can be solved by using the quadratic formula.

$$u = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{49}}{2}$$

$$u = \frac{1 \pm 7}{2}$$

$$u = \frac{8}{2},- \frac{6}{2}$$

$$u = 4,-3$$

Now we recall that $u=x^3$ and conclude that,

$$ x = 4^{1/3},- 3^{1/3}$$

We now conclude that all the roots of the given polynomial are,

$$ \boxed{ x = 0, 4^{1/3}, -3^{1/3}}$$

Comment: is there any to it other than this? i figured that perhaps thms would be needed rather than straight manipulation?

Comment: Its just straight manipulation. You should have encountered polynomials of this kind in your trigonometry or pre-calculus class (I wouldn't blame you if you don't remember). There is nothing specifically that you would learn in calculus that would help you solve this kind of problem.

Comment: If your professor gives you a high degree polynomial and asks you to find the roots there is always going to be some kind of trick Either some of the roots will be easy to guess and you can use polynomial division to factor them out, or the polynomial is really just a secret quadratic.

Comment: As other commenters have pointed out there is *no* general method for factoring polynomials of degree higher than *5*. The general method for even just factoring cubics is extremely laborious and most mathematicians never even learn it, much less calculus students.

Comment: hmm ok thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=x(x^6-x^3-12)=x(x^3+3)(x^3-4)=0\iff$
$x=0$ or $x^3+3=0$ or $x^3-4=0$. Can you take it from here?